# UserDefaults data validation in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, validation

I want to validate my NSUserDefaults string value by using `if` condition. I have done the following code but I am looking for better way to validate.

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"colordatafromthisvc"];

NSLog(@"%@colorValue---", savedValue);

if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"black"]) {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
} else if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"pink"]) {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
} else if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
} else if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else if ([savedValue isEqualToString:@"yellow"]) {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
} else {
    _imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    [_imglet setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    _btnlet.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid boilerplate you can use `NSDictionary` with all valid options.

```
NSDictionary *colors = @{@"black", [UIColor blackColor], @"pink": [UIColor purpleColor], @"blue": [UIColor blueColor], @"red": [UIColor redColor], @"yellow": [UIColor yellowColor]};
```

With this dictionary your code should look as follows:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"colordatafromthisvc"];
UIColor *color = colors[savedValue] ?: [UIColor orangeColor];
_imglet.image = [_imglet.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[_imglet setTintColor:color];
_btnlet.tintColor = color;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sviatoslav Yakymiv .. This is what i am expecting.